# Multiple python processes in Foreman stop logging

Tags: python, logging, heroku, foreman

I am running two python processes (clock and web) through Heroku and [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman)

When I run locally with Foreman:
1. Both processes log to terminal
2. Then the clock process stops outputting (even though its still running). This halting of the output doesn't happen at a consistent place in the code but usually somewhere between 3-5 iterations.
3. The web process continues to output correctly.

Oddly enough, when I run the same code on Heroku, the logs output just fine.

We have PYTHONUNBUFFERED set to true locally (with .env) and on Heroku. Has anybody come across this issue? Is there a solution to it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't fix this problem with Foreman, but I did come up with solution. There is a python port of Foreman called [honcho](https://github.com/nickstenning/honcho). I've switched to honcho and it fixed my logging/freezing issue.